# VSCode extension runs from development but does not work when packaged using webpack

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've built, run, packaged, and published an extension but the packager complains about 2509 files, 4.28MB and suggested using a bundler. I've followed the instructions on [Bundling Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension) and finally got it to build and run in my development environment using the extensionHost.

After publishing this new package (14 files, 303.51KB) I find that while my contributed viewContainer and views are visible, it appears that my activate() function is never called. I've put `vscode.window.showInformationMessage()` and it shows up fine with the extensionHost but not when installed from a `.vsix`. I've looked at `dist/extension.js` and confirmed that my code is present, so it isn't exactly that webpack is missing something.

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/jgfoster/vscode-gemstone). I'd really appreciate any advice. Why would webpack work in development but not in a vsce package? Thanks!

Comment: After installing that extension from the marketplace, the following is logged to my Developer Tools console: "Activating extension `jgfoster.gemstone` failed: jgfoster.gemstone-0.2.1\node_modules\ref-napi\build\Release\binding.node is not a valid Win32 application."

Comment: Thanks for trying. I have been developing on macOS and didn't realize there was a difference for Win32. The problem I'm having is with version 0.2.2.