# Webpack 5 entry point

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, vscode-extensions

This is NOT a duplicate of [VSCode extension runs from development but does not work when packaged using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56712315/vscode-extension-runs-from-development-but-does-not-work-when-packaged-using-web) although the symptoms are identical until you use the developer tools to see the actual error.

Packaging a VSCode extension using webpack, a dist folder is created containing the files I expect.

The extension works find in the extension host, but when installed from the generated VSIX the extension activate method is not called, despite all the expected files being present in `C:\Users\Peter\.vscode\extensions\pdconsec.vscode-print-0.7.20`

In Visual Studio Code, Developer Tools pane reveals

```
Activating extension 'pdconsec.vscode-print' failed: Cannot find module 
'c:\Users\Peter\.vscode\extensions\pdconsec.vscode-print-0.7.20\out\extension.js'
Require stack:
- c:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js
- c:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-amd.js
- c:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-fork.js.
```

and this is the wrong path. It should read

```
'c:\Users\Peter\.vscode\extensions\pdconsec.vscode-print-0.7.20\dist\extension.js'
```

This seems like a configuration problem. I expected to find the culprit in `webpack.config.js`, but "out" does not appear in that file except as part of "output". Here's the entire file in case that helps.

```
//@ts-check

'use strict';

const path = require('path');

/**@type {import('webpack').Configuration}*/
const config = {
  target: 'node', // vscode extensions run in a Node.js-context  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/

  entry: './src/extension.ts', // the entry point of this extension,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
  output: { // the bundle is stored in the 'dist' folder (check package.json),  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'extension.js',
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: "../[resource-path]",
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  externals: {
    vscode: "commonjs vscode" // the vscode-module is created on-the-fly and must be excluded. Add other modules that cannot be webpack'ed,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
  },
  resolve: { // support reading TypeScript and JavaScript files,  -> https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      // vscode-nls-dev loader:
      // * rewrite nls-calls
      loader: 'vscode-nls-dev/lib/webpack-loader',
      options: {
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.ts$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          compilerOptions: {
            "module": "es6" // override `tsconfig.json` so that TypeScript emits native JavaScript modules.
          }
        }
      }]
    }]
  },
}

module.exports = config;
```

Reviewing https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension

> In the sample above, the following are defined:
>
> - The target is 'node' because extensions run in a Node.js context.
> - The entry point webpack should use. This is similar to the main property in package.json except that you provide webpack with a "source" entry point, usually src/extension.ts, and not an "output" entry point. The webpack bundler understands TypeScript, so a separate TypeScript compile step is redundant.
> - The output configuration tells webpack where to place the generated bundle file. By convention, that is the dist folder. In this sample, webpack will produce a dist/extension.js file.
>   The resolve and module/rules configurations are there to support TypeScript and JavaScript input files.

What controls the path for the entry point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that `package.json` contains

```
  "main": "./out/extension.js",
```

and changing this to

```
  "main": "./dist/extension.js",
```

didn't seem to affect running in the extension host.

Bumping the version and building a new VSIX we find that the entry point path is now correct and the activate method runs.