# ERROR Extension entrypoint(s) missing while I'm trying to package a developed vscode extension with vsce

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a VSCode extension to automate some edit & search processes. Everything runs Ok! in the Extension Development Host but when I try to package the extension with vsce inside the extension's folder the app responds with this error:

```
 ERROR  Extension entrypoint(s) missing. Make sure these files exist and aren't ignored by '.vscodeignore':
  extension/extension.js
```

At the extension's manifest(**package.json**) the entrypoint to the extension code is defined in the "main" key:

```json
...
"activationEvents": [
        "onCommand:extension.findBlock"
],
"main": "./extension.js",
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
        "command": "extension.findBlock",
        "title": "Find Block"
        }
    ],
...
```

In the extension's folder everything is as the visual studio extension generator(yo) left it.

```
.
├── block_finder.code-workspace
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── extension.js
├── findBlock.png
├── jsconfig.json
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── prueba.txt
├── README.md
├── test
└── vsc-extension-quickstart.md
```

Am I missing something? I don't understand what could be happening. My VSCode version is 1.65.2 and vsce is 2.7.0. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it is getting confused by using `extension` as your command ids?  Since it is looking for `extension/extension.js` for some odd reason.  Try `"command": "block-finder.findBlock",` and same in `activationEvents`.

Comment: Hey @Mark, thanks for your time! I've tried your suggestions but `vsce package` keeps looking for `extension/extension.js`. I've created a folder `/extension` and put the extension code (extension.js) in it but now vsce looks for `extension/extension/extension.js` hahaha! It's my first extension, it's ready but I can't install it and use it. :(

Comment: I guess you could try: `"main": "extension.js",` or `"main": "../extension.js",` but they shouldn't make a difference.  You may have to restart making the extension and don't use the name `extension` for anything other than your `extension.js`.

Comment: Did you fix your problem? What was the cause?

Comment: Did you find fix for this issue?

Comment: Check this answer about /dist/extension instead of /out/extension on the package.json  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64788012/1461862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back to say that I solved the problem by uninstalling the npm manager. The version I had installed was old and I noticed that in the installation of the extension requirements it installed packages with warnings of deprecated versions. I uninstalled npm and did a clean install and my extension started working as expected. Sorry for leaving this post open and thanks for all the help you have given me.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a week trying to solve this.
And it turns out the solution is quite simple.
Uninstall Node.js and npm from the operating system.
Install the latest version of Node.js, which I am currently using:

node -v

```
v20.3.1
```

npm -v

```
9.7.2
```

And that immediately resolved my issue.
If it reoccurs, it might be worth considering using an even newer version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the following `.vscodeignore` file:

```bash
# Ignore everything
**

# Include specific files
!/out/*
!/CHANGELOG.md
!/LICENSE.md
!/package.json
!/README.md
```

Removing all the `/` prefixes fixed the issue:

```bash
# Ignore everything
**

# Include specific files
!out/*
!CONTRIBUTING.md
!CHANGELOG.md
!LICENSE.md
!package.json
!README.md
```