# ERROR: Extension entrypoint(s) missing. Make sure these files exist and aren't ignored by '.vscodeignore': extension/dist/extension.js

Tags: webpack, vscode-extensions, yo

I tried to make my own extension for Visual Studio Code and ran in some issue.
I did everything like in the guide from https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension.
My vsce version is 2.16.0, my npm version is 9.2.0

First I ran

```bash
yo code
```

and generated an extension with the name "test". Then I ran

```bash
cd test
vsce package
```

and expected a file called something like `test.vsix` but got the following error:

```
 ERROR  Extension entrypoint(s) missing. Make sure these files exist and aren't ignored by '.vscodeignore':
  extension/dist/extension.js
```

The file mentioned in the error message (`.vscodeignore`):

```
.vscode/**
.vscode-test/**
out/**
node_modules/**
src/**
.gitignore
.yarnrc
webpack.config.js
vsc-extension-quickstart.md
**/tsconfig.json
**/.eslintrc.json
**/*.map
**/*.ts
```

But even if I empty this file there is still the same error. Why? What did I forget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why, but it seems like the default npm and node versions on Linux just don't work correctly in that case. Like in [ERROR Extension entrypoint(s) missing while I'm trying to package a developed vscode extension with vsce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71686135/error-extension-entrypoints-missing-while-im-trying-to-package-a-developed-vs)

I completely uninstalled node and npm from my system, even deleted the `npm` directory from my global `node_modules` and then followed the guide on https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#using-ubuntu to reinstall everything.

Now it suddenly works...

Answer (score 3):

my problem is in my package.json `"main": "./out/extension.js"` is incorrect, should be `"main": "./dist/extension.js"`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar trouble.

- I had a working VSCode extension, but `vsce package` (latest version, v2.15.0) was warning about unnecessary files being included:

```
This extension consists of 421 files, out of which 196 are JavaScript files. For performance reasons, you should bundle your extension: https://aka.ms/vscode-bundle-extension . You should also exclude unnecessary files by adding them to your .vscodeignore: https://aka.ms/vscode-vscodeignore
```

- Tried using `esbuild` but it gave warnings about one of my included packages which I could not solve (`import * as FormData from 'form-data';`
  )
- Tried following the instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension#publishing) to reduce the package size. Code ran well under the extension debugging host, but broke when installing from local `.vsix` or Marketplace.
- I had to undo the `.vscodeignore` changes, [here](https://github.com/tuck1s/taxitest/commits/master/.vscodeignore). Seems like I need `node_modules` and (probably) `webpack.config.js` files.

Answer (score 0):

My extension.js file was in `out` folder. and in `.vscodeignore` file I have out/** like you. After delete this line, it passed